# What is this default tolerance value for Binary (as well as other types of) variables in CPLEX?

Tags: variables, mathematical-optimization, cplex, docplex, fault-tolerance

Elaborating on the question, say the optimal solution has a few binary variables which are assigned to 0's and 1's; in reality when comparing these variables,we will often get their values as slightly higher or lower than what they should be exactly.

The absolute range of this slight variation is 10E-5 for Gurobi.(https://www.gurobi.com/documentation/9.5/refman/grb_tolerances_and_the_lim.html).

I need to know what is this default tolerance for CPLEX (I am using the latest CPLEX version using the Python wrapper docplex).

Comment: The default value of this tolerance is the same in CPLEX as well. (Refer: https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/icos/22.1.1?topic=parameters-integrality-tolerance ; https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58105076/influence-of-tolerances-on-the-binary-variable)

Answer (score 0):

I confirm this parameter controls integer tolerance in MIP problems, not only for binary variables, but also for all integer variables.

Answer (score 0):

The default value of this tolerance is the same in CPLEX as well.

(Refer: https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/icos/22.1.1?topic=parameters-integrality-tolerance; [Influence of tolerances on the binary variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58105076/influence-of-tolerances-on-the-binary-variable))

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).